# Progress bar on splash screen in eclipse 4 RCP application

Tags: eclipse

I want to add a progress bar to my eclipse 4 RCP splash screen. I have tried the following code and settings but still unable to get the progress bar....

org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_PROGRESS_ON_STARTUP = true 
in plugin_customization.ini file

i have set the plugin name in which splash.bmp file exist..

```
enter code here
<plugin>

<extension
     id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        name="com.example.e4.wizard"
        application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
      <property name="preferenceCustomization" value="plugin_customization.ini"/>
      <property name="startupForegroundColor" value="FFFF80"/>
      <property name="startupMessageRect" value="250,44,250,20"/>
      <property name="startupProgressRect" value="250,64,501,15"/>
      <property
           name="appName"
           value="com.example.e4.wizard">
     </property>
  </product>
 </extension>
```

plugin.xml

Comment: The configuration in the question worked for me. I didn't need to use the custom splash screen handler described in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your demand you need to create a lifecycle hook and custom splashscreen handler. Lars Vogel wrote an excellent tutorial about this topic:

[http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html#lifecycle_overview](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html)

You can also use an OSGi service instead of the lifecycle extension. For more information please check [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382224) as well as the example code attached to it.