# Eclipse E4 - Adding progress bar to splash image

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I'm trying to add a progress bar to a splash view, but I'm not able to succeed.

This is what I did, but the bar is not shown on startup:

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: Unfortunately the progress bar part of the splash screen is not currently supported for a e4 application. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24305651/2670892) has some more on this.

Comment: Is it going to be added in future upgrades?

Comment: I don't know. It is possible to do yourself but does involve quite a lot of tricky code.

Comment: There is a sample appended to this feature request: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382224